# Running cucumber BDD in GCP for Dataproc spark job testing

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, automated-tests, bigdata, google-cloud-dataproc

Currently my BDD is running on On-premise Hadoop cluster where it establishes JDBC connection and runs BDDs. Following are the steps done through BDD.

- Insert required data in Hive and Hbase tables
- Run spark job
- Verify data that is loaded into target tables (by spark job)

I need to achieve the same in GCP where Dataproc cluster is being used for spark jobs. Any help is much appreciated.